# how to show preselected status of primeng inputSwitch under form?

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng

I am reading the offical Primeng docs below:

http://primefaces.org/primeng/inputswitch

I can see how to make `p-inputSwitch` preselected by default with `[(ngModel)]`.

My question is how I can do the same thing under form? I understand I cannot use both `[(ngModel)]` and `formControlName` at the same time.

Can anyone please give me a simple example?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's in the [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-inputswitch-demo?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts,src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) of the official example you link to. Set the bound property to `true`.

```js
export class AppComponent { 
    checked2: boolean = true;
}
```

```html
<h5>Preselection</h5>
<p-inputSwitch [(ngModel)]="checked2"></p-inputSwitch>
```